# Set inner overflow element to the top left when large

Tags: css

I have a div that contains a canvas

The div has css on it that looks like this:

```
.workspace-area {
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 35px;
    bottom: 35px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The `canvas` has css on it that looks like this:

```
canvas {
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

The issue that I am having is when the canvas fits inside the div it is centered (which is what I want), but when the canvas is larger than the div it is still vertically centered, and the div overflow doesn't scroll to the top of the canvas, so the top of the canvas can't be scrolled to.

Here is a fiddle of what I mean, there are two canvases in the fiddle just for example. In the real application, there is only one canvas.

https://jsfiddle.net/q1j6sjcd/1/

So, basically:

- Small canvas should be centered
- Large canvas (overflow) should in the top left corner

Comment: I assume you're unable to modify or add classes/ids in one situation Vs. the other?

Comment: yeah probably not, when the canvas is created, I don't know if it will overflow or not. It should probably automatically know how to position itself.

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no CSS-only solution. The closest I can think of is a JS test for size with a class being added to the canvas. I'm interested to see if anyone else has a working solution for this though.

Comment: it works if I remove the `bottom` attribute when it is overflowing, so if I can somehow remove the `bottom` attribute on larger items, that would be helpful.

Comment: I won't disagree - it's extremely close, and seems almost within reach - but for the life of me I can't see how it could be done.